# Wordpress Visual Composer Sidebar

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, plugins

I have some problems. We must work on a page from another agency. They write something to show a Sidebar. The site uses Visual Composer.

I must add menu-item classes to the

Tag (for example menu-item-112 and so on).

Here is the following code:

```
<?php
function sidenavi_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
  global $post;

  $walker = array();
  $complete = false;

  $the_post = $post;

  while(!$complete) {
    array_push($walker, $the_post->ID);

    if($the_post->post_parent == 0) {
      $complete = true;
    }
    else {
      $the_post = get_post($the_post->post_parent);
    }
  }

  $content = recursive_side_navi($walker, $walker[count($walker) - 1], false, true);

  return $content;
}
function recursive_side_navi($walker, $pid, $expand_all = false, $start = false) {
  $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $pages = $wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page',
                                   'post_parent' => $pid,
                                   'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                                   'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                   'order' => 'ASC'));

  $content = '';
  if(count($pages)) {
    if($start) {
      $content = '<ul class="sidenav">';
      $the_post = get_post($walker[count($walker) - 1]);
      $pid = 
      $content.= '<li class="active"><a href="'.get_permalink($the_post->ID).'">'.$the_post->post_title.'</a></li><br />';
    }
    else {
      $content = '<ul>';
    }

    foreach($pages as $page) {
      $active = false;
      foreach($walker as $item) {
        if($item == $page->ID) $active = true;
      }
      $content.= '<li'.($active ? ' class="active"' : '').'><a href="'.get_permalink($page->ID).'">'.$page->post_title.'</a>';
      if($expand_all || $active) {
        $content.= recursive_side_navi($walker, $page->ID);
      }
      $content.= '</li>';
    }
    $content.= '</ul>';
  }

  return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'sm_sidenavi', 'sidenavi_func' );

vc_map( array(
   "name" => __("Sidebar Navigation"),
   "base" => "sm_sidenavi",
   "class" => "sidenavi",
   "category" => __('Content'),
   'admin_enqueue_js' => '',
   'admin_enqueue_css' => array(get_template_directory_uri().'/vc_extend/style.css'),
   'show_settings_on_create' => false,
   'custom_markup ' => '<div style="float: left; color: #d2e3ff; border: 1px solid #669fff; padding: 14px;"><p style="color: #669fff; padding: 30px 0; text-align: center;">Sidebar Navigation</p></div>'
   )
);
?>
```

Comment: What is the question? Also note that Stackoverflow is not intended as a code-writing organization. Users on this site are here to help with programming questions/problems, not to take over your work. Please indicate what you have tried, what specifically is going wrong and how you have attempted debugging or getting closer to a solution.